# Is there any GLES #define in C?

Tags: opengl-es

I'm working with a codebase that supports OpenGL and OpenGL ES.

Is there any GLES define I can use to write conditional code in C? Something like:

```c
#include <GLES/gl.h>

#ifdef __GLES
 //
#else
 //
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## In GLSL shaders

For conditional compilation of GLSL shaders, there is `GL_ES`. The [GLSL ES 1.00 specification](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) defines under section 3.4 "Preprocessor":

> The following predefined macros are available
>
> `__LINE__`
>
> `__FILE__`
>
> `__VERSION__`
>
> `GL_ES`
>
> `GL_ES` will be defined and set to 1. This is not true for the non-ES OpenGL Shading Language, so it can
> be used to do a compile time test to see whether a shader is running on ES.

So you can check for `GL_ES` in shaders.

## In host/C code

If you want to know whether any particular C file is being compiled in a project for a particular version of OpenGL ES, then you can use the defines from `GLES/gl.h`, `GLES2/gl2.h`, `GLES3/gl3.h`, `GLES3/gl31.h` or `GLES3/gl32.h`, which are: `GL_VERSION_ES_CM_1_0`, `GL_ES_VERSION_2_0`, `GL_ES_VERSION_3_0`, `GL_ES_VERSION_3_1` and `GL_ES_VERSION_3_2`, respectively. Starting with `GLES2/gl2.h` and anything above, you will always have the defines of the previous versions (up to GLES 2.0) also defined. So when you include `GLES3/gl31.h` then you will find `GL_ES_VERSION_2_0`, `GL_ES_VERSION_3_0` and `GL_ES_VERSION_3_1` to be defined.

However, you make the decision in your application whether to include the OpenGL Desktop header files or the OpenGL ES header files and you could use that same condition for conditionally compiling code that relies on you compiling for either OpenGL Desktop or OpenGL ES. So, you really don't need any pre-defined defines because you make the decision yourself earlier in the program about which header you include.